# How to send consecutive data from Matlab socket client to C socket server?

Tags: python, c, matlab, sockets, redpitaya

I'm working with a RedPitaya Development Board, which runs Linux. The application requires communication between a socket server running on the board and a remote client running on Matlab. The C server code that I'm using has probed to work with a Python client, so, I'm trying to recreate that Python client with my own modifications to make it fit with my needs.

I'm passing four numbers as data, but only one is making it to the server.

The Systems works with numbers in uint32 format, every byte has different meaning to the system, I've tried change the data type that the Matlab clients send, change if the operation is sync or async type, send it as string, but just the first data sent appears to get response form the server

This is the part of the C server that receives the data:

```
 if(bind(sock_server, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
 {
   perror("bind");
   return EXIT_FAILURE;
 }
 listen(sock_server, 1024);
 printf("Listening on port serverPort ...\n");

 while(1)
{

if((sock_client = accept(sock_server, NULL, NULL)) < 0)
{
  perror("accept");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
while(1) //MSG_WAITALL
{
  //sleep(1);
  rx = recv(sock_client, (char *)&command, 4, MSG_DONTWAIT);
  if (rx == 0) {
     break;
     measuring = 0;
  }
  if(rx > 0) {
     value = command & 0xfffffff;
     switch(command >> 28)
     {
       case 1: /* Trigger Delay - Timing */
            timing = command & 0xff;
                            printf("timing: %zu \n",timing);
            break;

       case 2: /* NSAMPLES */
            if ((command & 0xff) < 10)
                nsamples = (command & 0xff);
            else
            nsamples = 10;
                            printf("samples: %zu \n",nsamples);
            break;

       case 3: /* NAVERAGES */
            naverages = command & 0xff;
                            printf("averages: %zu \n",naverages);
            break;

       case 0: /* fire */
         
            // set trigger and NSAMPLES set NAVERAGES and stop measurement
            *((int32_t *)(cfg + 0)) = (STOP) + (timing<<8) + (nsamples<<16) + (naverages<<24);

            //sleep(0.1); // wait 0.1 second

            time_begin = clock();
            // start measurement
            *((int32_t *)(cfg + 0)) ^= 1;
            measuring = 1;
            break;
     }
  }
```

The Python client sends data in this way:

```
if self.idle: return
self.socket.write(struct.pack('<I', 1<<28 | self.cbTrigger.currentIndex()))
self.socket.write(struct.pack('<I', 2<<28 | self.cbNOS.currentIndex()))
self.socket.write(struct.pack('<I', 3<<28 | self.cbNOA.currentIndex()))
```

The matlab client is rather simple:

```
t=tcpip('RedPitayaIP',serverPort,'NetworkRole','client')
pause(1);
fopen(t);
```

And I'm sending data in this way:

```
fwrite(t,variable_trigger_or,'uint32')
fwrite(t,variable_samples_or,'uint32')
fwrite(t,variable_average_or,'uint32')
```

The Python client send data and the client give this response:

```
Litening to port serverPort
timing: 16
samples: 10
averages: 0
```

And the Matlab client only gets this

```
Listening to port serverPort
timing: 16
```

So, I'll be glad if anyone could help me understand what's happening, or if I'm missing something, I'm not new at this but also not close to be an expert

Comment: There are multiple exits in your code not printing anything, 1) rx==0, 2) commands other than 0...3, 3) nsamples<10 4) command 4 has no print. Put a different print for each of these situations to know what's actually happening.

Comment: There is no error in the C code, as I said on the post, it works, paired with the Python client, the issue here is that using that same code with a Matlab client only gets response for thr first value passed to the server, then it does nothing.
rx just recieves the data from the connected socket, as long as I get the first connection and data pass done, i'ts clear that the issue isn't there, commands other than 0-3 can't happen because of how the system is designed, and nsamples can be greater than 10 because hardware limitations, just want to understand what's different between the 2 clients

Comment: Little update, found that server when paired with Python client, the server recieves rx=4, and when paired with Matlab client it recieves that rx=4 on the first write, but then begins to recieve rx=-1, so, it didn't get back to the switch statement.

Comment: New update:
I've used <errno.h> to catch the error on recv(), and I got a "Resource temporarily unavailable(11)"  message, what does that means?, what is my Matlab client missing that Python does have?

Comment: "_The Systems works with numbers in uint32 format, every byte has different meaning to the system_" Why do you group your _independent_ bytes by pack of 4 then ? Would you really need all these back and forth `<<28` and `>>28` on both sides ?

Comment: Do you know the endianness of both your systems ? Does Python send the 4 bytes of an `uint32` in the same order than Matlab ?

Comment: The logic shift are meant to identify every data trough the switch statement, and about the endianness of both systems, yes, they are in the same order, I forgot to mention that I've already checked that